# Mongoose Transaction 1 has been committed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to have two operations under a transaction.

```js
const instance = new Model(data);
const session = await mongoose.startSession();

await session.withTransaction(async () => {
  await Model.updateOne(
    filterQuery,
    updateQuery,
    { session }
  );
  instance = await instance.save({ session });
});

await session.endSession();
```

This part of the code is working fine. But the problem is, I also have a post save hook, which updates some field of the saved instance.

```js
ModelSchema.post('save', (doc, next) => {
  const instance = this;
  instance.field = updatedValue();
  instance.save((err) => {
    if (err) log(err);
    next();
  });
});
```

The save operation on the hook fails and raises `MongoError: Transaction 1 has been committed.` I am confused as this operation was not included in the session. Is there any workaround to avoid this error and have the save operation in post save hook?

Comment: If you want to modify data before save then you need to use ModelSchema.pre('save').

Comment: the modification actually requires the instance to be saved first.

Comment: In that case you need to make separate save query instead of post.save hook.